# share data between postman and Java

Tags: java, rest, postman

I’m in the process of building a restful service, but I’ve never done it before so I’m starting very simple.
My first objective would be to have a simple class – which will eventually be my controller – and, for now to keep things simple, use a service like postman to send mock data to this class and return that data from it, just to get a feel for how the whole thing works and then expand from that.
I’m using Eclipse and I’ve built a very simple class which has only one property, an id.

```
package controller;
public class EmployeeController
{
    private int id;

    public EmployeeController(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getEmployeeID(){
        return id;
    }
    public void setID(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Now if I understand things correctly, postman can be used as a service to send and receive data to and from this class, is that correct?
I’ve installed it in my chrome apps, but how do I get it to communicate with my java class?
I’ve found [an interesting article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-postman-to-manage-and-execute-your-apis) which kind of explain how to send data etc but I can’t find anything that explains – if at all possible – how to send and retrieve data to and from a java class. Any idea of what I need to get started?
thanks

Comment: *"postman can be used as a service to send and receive data to and from this class"* - ehm NO! Postman can be used to send HTTP request to any URL you wish. If you setup a java project and run it in a way that it is exposed at e.g. http://localhost:1234 *THEN* you can use postman to send request there. A simple java class itself has nothing to do with postman or rest or anything networking related, you need some infrastructure around that.

Comment: Postman is a REST client sending HTTP request and receiving the response. That's all. You should take a look to `jee` to understand how to create a webservice

Comment: Understood, thanks for clarifying it @luk2302. I've now reused the same class as above and run the maven project on http://localhost:8088/EmployeeRest/index.jsp. Does it mean that now, in theory, I can send a HTTP request to set that id and another one to retrieve it with postman?

Comment: Maybe... I do not know - you should read some tutorials regarding that topic, giving you a basic jee + rest tutorial is out of scope for a question on SO.